# D3 Brush & Zoom Data not showing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, d3.js

i have this graph which is not showing the values but the shape only.
i am loading my json object from backend and only 2 fields.
Any help would be really apperciate.
Month and count

```
[{"Count":50,"Month":"February 2014"},{"Count":66,"Month":"March 2014"},{"Count":69,"Month":"April 2014"},{"Count":57,"Month":"May 2014"},{"Count":85,"Month":"June 2014"},{"Count":81,"Month":"July 2014"},{"Count":117,"Month":"August 2014"},{"Count":154,"Month":"September 2014"},{"Count":144,"Month":"October 2014"},{"Count":162,"Month":"November 2014"},{"Count":191,"Month":"December 2014"},{"Count":211,"Month":"January 2015"},{"Count":134,"Month":"February 2015"},{"Count":207,"Month":"March 2015"},{"Count":157,"Month":"April 2015"},{"Count":155,"Month":"May 2015"},{"Count":167,"Month":"June 2015"},{"Count":143,"Month":"July 2015"},{"Count":183,"Month":"September 2015"},{"Count":137,"Month":"August 2015"},{"Count":179,"Month":"October 2015"},{"Count":161,"Month":"November 2015"},{"Count":174,"Month":"December 2015"},{"Count":180,"Month":"January 2016"},{"Count":170,"Month":"February 2016"},{"Count":166,"Month":"March 2016"},{"Count":175,"Month":"April 2016"},{"Count":173,"Month":"May 2016"},{"Count":158,"Month":"June 2016"},{"Count":129,"Month":"July 2016"},{"Count":153,"Month":"August 2016"},{"Count":114,"Month":"September 2016"},{"Count":112,"Month":"October 2016"},{"Count":143,"Month":"November 2016"},{"Count":126,"Month":"December 2016"},{"Count":98,"Month":"January 2017"},{"Count":138,"Month":"February 2017"},
```

i Copy the codes from

[the link here D3 website](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172)

and change
this line

`d3.csv("sp500.csv", type, function(error, data) {`

To

```
d3.json('@Url.Action("GetStatistic", "JuraServicing")', function (error, data) {



 data = jsondata;
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.Month; }));
 y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.Count; })]);
```

it also shows the error which i don't understand

> d3.v4.min.js:2 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNCNaN,NaN,…".

**This is what i am getting**
[image: This is what i get]

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to update the time parser. This line:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%b %Y");
```

...parses the date in the form `Jan 2001`, but your date is of the form `January 2001`. You should change it to an uppercase B for full month name:

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%B %Y");
```

See this page for information on d3 time format specifiers: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format.

Comment: Hi, i am getting the same thing. could it be the `Mnan` Error?